# Can complex logical expressions be used in #ifdef in C++?

Tags: c++, conditional-compilation

I have found that one can combine multiple `#ifdef`s using command `#if defined(STUFF)` this way:

```
#if defined(_BLA1) || defined(_BLA2)
```

or

```
#if defined(_BLA1) && defined(_BLA2)
```

But can I use parentheses to combine more refined definitions, such as:

```
#if (defined(_BLA1) || defined(_BLA2)) && (defined(_BLA3) || defined(_BLA4))
```

?

Comment: Ask a compiler, not stack overflow.

Comment: @YSC I'm not so sure about that. Just because something is considered simple, doesn't mean it is not welcome here. And there is a big difference between what you observe with a compiler, and what is guaranteed by The Standard (which admittedly makes the current answer bad). The asker obviously had to stop and think about this, came here looking for an answer and didn't find one, so tried to extend the useful knowledge here. Yet I couldn't quite bring myself to upvote it either, since it seems like something that *should* be answerable by searching (SO or Google).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works fine. I have tested it in Xcode, which uses LLVM compiler.